# Issue adding headers to a csv file

Tags: bash, csv

I need to copy headers from a CSV file into a new CSV file.

input.csv content :

```
col1;col2;col3
```

For that, I used the following command :

```
head -n 1 input.csv > output.csv
```

and I also tried :

```
awk -F\; 'NR==1 {print; exit}' input.csv > output.csv
```

The result is the same. Doing that, headers are copied into output.csv, but the issue is that they are all copied into the same cell, instead of creating distinct columns.

*cell A1 of output.csv content : col1 col2 col3*

It seems that the seperators `;` are removed in the process and I can't figure out why.

Would anyone have an explanation and eventually a solution ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you're operating on it as a text file there's no knowledge of columns.

Comment: `head` won't remove semicolons. Maybe the problem is with how you're importing `output.csv` into the spreadsheet application?

Comment: The normal field delimiters for CSV are commas or tabs, not semicolons.

Comment: Semicolons were removed by an awk command later in the script, which is explained by RavinderSingh13

Comment: @GFO_ADS, if it worked for you, I undeleted my answer now, thought it was wrong.

Comment: But `head -1` doesn't do anything to semicolons, that simple version should have worked.

Comment: Your original solution using `head` is fine, and actually the best one. It does not silently transform your line. You can verify this by doing `head -n 1 input.csv > output.csv; cat output.csv`, or with less typing `head -n 1 input.csv |tee output.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mention OFS(output field separator) value as ; to get them in different columns. Could you please try following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} FNR==1 {print;exit}' input.csv > output.csv
```

***Reason why semi colons in output are getting disappeared?*** There is a term called output field separator which is denoted with OFS in awk programming. So whenever it is NOT set by us specifically then its value is space. Hence we need to set it to ; like I did in above code to get column's separator preserved in output too.

Comment: `OFS` is only used if the line has to be regenerated from fields. If you don't assign to `$something` it keeps the line unchanged.